# Git undo pushed commits (deleted folder by mistake) that have other commits on top

Tags: git

Ok so I deleted a folder by mistake and pushed that change

I then reverted, and `committed again, and`pushed
then I continued to work for 2 months

Now I noticed, that all my annotates basically read "whops delete by mistake"

is there a way to delete just the delete folder plus revert of the delete, and keep everything else?

I work by myself, no team members, no worries about having it checked out or whatever

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to delete just the delete folder plus revert of the delete, and keep everything else?

1. Not clear what do you mean "delete just the delete folder"
2. revert of the delete

   ```
   # Undo any change based upon the commit SHA1 (or multiple)
   git revert SHA-1 SHA-2 ...  SHA-N
   ```

---

> Now I noticed, that all my annotates basically read "whops delete by mistake"

#### How to fund out the last commit of a file

```
git log -n 1 -- <file path>
```

Now use this SHA to checkout the desired content

```
git checkout <SHA-1> -- <path>
```

Comment: I want to erase pushed commits say SHA-1 and SHA-2 so they don't appear in the git history at all. I deleted a folder by mistake. I want to erase that delete from git altogether. `Revert` imho does not delete entries from the git log. I want to erase/destroy/delete something I did from git altogether.

Comment: ping me tommorow and ill guide you, out of the office today

Answer (score 1):

Since you're the master of your ship here (history rewrites allowed as you mentioned), I'd suggest **interactive rebasing** here*. ([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode))

And before starting, *since this is a touchy operation, as reminded by Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen [right below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54915901/git-undo-pushed-commits-deleted-folder-by-mistake-that-have-other-commits-on-t/54916280#comment96606837_54916280), it is strongly advised that you backup your branch* (with `git branch <backupBranch> <originalBranch>` for example).

First search for the two commits' SHA-1 hashes (deletion and undeletion) through `git log`. (I'll assume you can do that but feel free to ask for details on that part if needed.)

Then with

```
git checkout <yourBranch>
git rebase -i <deletionCommit>^
```

(mind the caret to start interactive rebasing from the commit just *before* the deletion commit)

you'll get an open editor with a list of the commits from the specified point to HEAD, preceded by a keyword :

```
pick 295ea4a Some commit message
pick 9cb2b54 Some other commit message
pick fe91df1 Yet another commit message
```

Now change `pick` to `drop` for the two commits to drop, and close/save the editor.

And finish the rebase with

```
git rebase --continue
```

(if anything goes sideways, use `git rebase --abort` to restore things just before rebasing started)

And finally don't forget that you'll need to `git push -f <remote> <branch>` next time to update the old ref, since every commit down the line will be different, be it only by the ref of their parent(s).

---

* (because after 2 monthes you may have a fair number of commits, so `git reset --hard <deletionCommit>^ && git cherry-pick <nextGoodCommit-1> <nextGoodCommit-2> <nextGoodCommit-3>` could be very tedious, and interactive rebase basically automates just that)

Comment: In addition to this answer, I'm going to post this message, please close your eyes and imagine it is displayed in big red blinking letters and that you can hear the old james bond alarm sound in the background: **MAKE SURE YOU HAVE A BACKUP BEFORE YOU START DOING THIS**.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Ha this is so true... after a while I tend to forget to always repeat it but I agree : each time you're not 100% sure of what you're doing on a branch, back it up before anything. git is easily put in sandbox mode, you can clone your repo and try anything on the clone, etc. Let's also mention that you'd always have your reflog in case of an emergency. But you're right, I'll edit to stress that point.